# How do I run the Visual Studio (2017) Installer?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-10, visual-studio-2017

It's probably really obvious once you know the answer, but I can't find it anywhere.

I'm not talking about *making* an installer, I'm talking about running the installer that lets me modify which features of Visual Studio 2017 are installed.

The main screen looks like this:

[image]

the screen I need is this one:

[image]

In Visual Studio 2017, there is a menu entry for "Extensions and Updates" under the Tool menu that doesn't take me to this application.
There is also a "NuGet Package Manager" which isn't even close.

In my Windows 10 start menu, I see Visual Studio 2017 itself, and a folder named "Visual Studio 2017" that contains a couple of command prompts and a "Debuggable Package Manager".

In the Control Panel - Programs and Features, I see Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 but right-click only gives me "Uninstall".

Comment: Did you *check* the list of programs in the Start Menu? Just hit the Win key and type `Visual Studio Installer`.

Comment: Searching for Visual Studio Installer gives me one match - "Search the web"

Comment: Then you didn't install it. *Did* you download the installer? Where did you put it? BTW where do these screenshots come from? This *is* the installer

Comment: Until Richard's answer below, I could only get to this screen when Visual Studio happened to give me a link to it.  There wasn't anything obvious to let me get to it when _I_ wanted to.

Comment: Go to `www.visualstudio.com`, click on `Download`, save the installer to the Downloads folder? If you clicked on `Open` instead of `Save As`, the installer was saved to a temporary folder by the browser. This has nothing to do with Visual Studio

Comment: check you Downloads folder

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The screenshots you show are the VS 2017 installer. This allows you to select from the large number of optional components that can be included in the VS install. Run by running the downloaded installed file you started the original install with.

Tools | Extensions and Updates is used to extend and service VS.

- Extensions are (usually third party) components to extend and enhance VS.
- Servicing: just a prompt that there is an update available, this takes you to the Visual Studio installer.

NuGet: is a package manager for projects built with VS. Adding a component that the software you are writing uses. Soemthing like jQuery in a web app. This does not change VS itself.

Comment: Doh!  As I suspected, something obvious.  Thanks.

Comment: How is this accepted answer? It doesn't tell you how to run the VS Installer which was the original question. The answer below with full path to executable or the one about running it from Control Panel are two ways of actually running the installer.

Comment: @DeanKuga The real question here is confusion between installing packages into a project (NuGet at al), adding extensions into VS, and the VS installer

Comment: @Richard The question was "How do I run the Visual Studio (2017) Installer?" followed by "I'm not talking about making an installer, I'm talking about running the installer that lets me modify which features of Visual Studio 2017 are installed.". That was not answered...

Answer (score 41):

I also found it a bit strange that you cannot modify the installation from *Control Panel - Programs and Features*. You can however launch the Visual Studio 2017 installer from the following location:

```
%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vs_installer.exe
```

Comment: Silly me, I was looking in Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0 !

Comment: There is a typo in the path, it should be (including quotes) "%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vs_installer.exe". But this is the info I was looking for. Even after installation of VS 2017 Update 2 failed the system did not give me a clue where to find the installer.

Comment: @TvdH, Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 11):

You can get to the installer via

> Control Panel --> Programs --> Programs and Features.

Select `Microsoft Visual Studio 2017` from the list and click `Change` at the top. The installer will magically open up.

Answer (score 3):

You can find Visual Studio Installer on below location

**`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer`**

Then search for `vs_installer`.

Answer (score 2):

My version of Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise has a Visual Studio Installer icon in the install folder under Programs. So go to Start --> Visual Studio Installer.

Answer (score 0):

Under Projects/New in VS there is a link to go to the Installer. That is the easiest way 
to start the Installer and get to the positions (panels) you want.