# Microsoft Bot Framework, there is a missing subtype

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, botframework

I am trying to create a Bot application using ms bot framework. I followed the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-quickstart). When I try to create a bot application using create new project in VS 2017 it gives an error.

[image]

> The project file cannot be opened.
>   There is a missing project subtype. Subtyle: '{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21}' is unsupported by this installation

I re-installed the vs 2017 twice but still, I am getting the error. Does anyone have an idea?

UPDATED!!!

when I try to install MVC 5 using command but it gives an error saying that "The current environment doesn't have a solution open."

> `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc -Version 5.2.4`

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See https://www.codeproject.com/Reference/720512/List-of-Visual-Studio-Project-Type-GUIDs

You are missing an installation for VS for MVC5. Use the VS installer or nuget to install it and update it to MVC5.

Link to MVC5 pages: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/mvc5,
Nuget: [MVC5.2.4](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I couldn't able to open Bot solution, so how should I stall MVC 5 without opening solution

Comment: @Roledenez Locate your VS Installer and install `ASP.NET and web development (under Web & Cloud)` as well as `.NET Core cross-platform development (under Other Toolsets)`  See [how-do-i-run-the-visual-studio-2017-installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43120912/how-do-i-run-the-visual-studio-2017-installer) for how to locate it